# How to index numpy array with an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array defined below as:

```
a = np.arange(30).reshape((3, 10)
col_index = [[1,2,3,5], [3,4,5,7]]
row_index = [2,1]
```

Is it possible to index `a[row_index, col_index]`, so I can do something like
`a[row_index, col_index] =1`, so then a becomes

`[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,1,1,1,16,1,18,19], [20,1,1,1,24,1,26,27,28,29]]`

So to clarify, in row 2, column 1,2,3, and 5 are set to one, and in row 1, column 3,4,5,7 is also set to 1.

Comment: OP, You can only accept one answer, not multiple. When you accept another answer, the first one is automatically unaccepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or (if you don't like typing)

```
a[np.c_[row_index], col_index] = 1
```

or even shorter but Python 2 only

```
a[zip(row_index), col_index] = 1
```

What all these solutions do is to make row and col indices [broadcastable](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to each other. `np.c_` is the column concatenation convenience object. It makes columns out of 1D objects.
`zip` used to do essentially the same. Only, since Python 3 it returns an iterator instead of a list and numpy can't handle those. (One could do `list(zip(row_index))` but that's not short.)